# django change foreignkey Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

this is my models.py

```
 class Equipment(models.Model):#table 
    equipment_Number = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=0,unique=True) #column
    equipment_Name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50,default='Dry')
    mfd = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today) #column
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    doors = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    locks = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.Make

class Inspection(models.Model):
    inspected = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)#the key that links the tables
    does_It_Work =  models.BooleanField(default=True)
    repairs = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    ins_date = models.DateTimeField( default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

this is my form.py

```
class EquipmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment

class InspectionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inspection
```

sorry, let me be more clear. with my code, the 'Inspection' class links to the 'Equipment' class by the 'make' property. I need it to link by the 'equipment_Number' property.

i changed the name of the equipment class to car as i thought it would make the concept more tangible and would make is easier for you all to help. turns out i just caused more confusion. thanks for all of your help. SO Rocks!

Comment: Can you please post exactly what fields the form is rendering (assuming you're displaying the whole form)? Also, the `Equipment` class?

Comment: Is the "inspection"  class the form you are loading? or are we missing more of the model? I'm not sure why "car" would even be in that model form since it's no where referenced in the inspection model.

Comment: I agree with sgarza62. What does ```Equipment``` look like? Why doesn't ```Inspection``` just link to ```Car``` directly? Also, you should really fix up your naming conventions. Class names should be capitalized - so ```Car``` not ```car```. Also, your properties should all be all lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a form for your `Equipment` model which displays only the `equipment_Number` field, then you would define it as follows in your `forms.py`:

```
class EquipmentNumberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Equipment
        fields = ['equipment_Number']
```

Saving this form (with it's POST data of course!) would create an instance of the `Equipment` model with the specified `equipment_Number`, and all other fields set to their default, or null value.

Note here that I set the `fields` attribute of the `Meta` class for the form. This is a list of strings which specifies which fields should be displayed by the form. You can, although this is not recommended, instead use the attribute `exclude`, which will show all fields except for the ones specified in your list.

[You can view the documentation here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/)

However, your question doesn't really make it clear if this is what you want.

As an aside, you should be careful with your naming conventions. Class names should always be `CamelCase` and attribute, variable, and method names should always be `lower_case_separated_by_underscores`. This will make your code much clearer to everyone who reads it, including yourself!

Comment: sorry, let me be more clear. with my code, the 'Inspection' class links to the 'Equipment' class by the 'make' property. I need it to link by the 'equipment_Number' property.